# Run js code when two fingers are swiped up using jQuery version of hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture, hammer.js

I've been playing around with hammer.js ( http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/ ) a multi-touch gesture library and I know how to execute js code when one finger is swiping up, or tapping or anything else, but could someone help me figure out how to run js code in the event of two finger both swiping up ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this issue(but  it is closed now) https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/34

In this they are trying to detect it by no. of touch.

May be you can take a look at this plugin also https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/plugins/hammer.showtouches.js

Comment: honestly i never tried that but i just found this information

Answer (score 1):

set the options swipe_max_touches to 2 or 0.

Comment: Thank you. I tried implementing that, but nothing seems to be happening on swipe-up. Here is the code of the page where nothing seems to be working: http://pastebin.com/b0TNiFrL

Answer (score 1):

you can try fingers.js (https://github.com/paztis/fingers.js).
It's a js lib like Hammer.js to manage touch events I've just develop.
Your case is in example pages.